How to specify jmx.remote.credentials from command-line?
The remote Java-process requires certain credentials for JMX-connections. Every time I invoke jconsole to check it, I need to retype the username and password -- and I'd like to skip that step.
It appears, the code looks for something called jmx.remote.credentials either in the process environment or among the Java properties -- and expects the entry to contain two strings: username and password.
However, I cannot figure out the syntax to use, none of the below worked:
jconsole -J-Djmx.remote.credentials="meow Wallabies" localhost:9581
jconsole -J-Djmx.remote.credentials='{"meow", "Wallabies"}' localhost:9581
env jmx.remote.credentials='{"meow", "Wallabies"}' jconsole localhost:9581

The online examples like this one show, how to do it in Java:
      String[] credentials = new String[] { "username" , "password" }; 
      env.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials); 
      JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL( 
         "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");       
      JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);

Is there a way to do it from shell?
